# How to replace/restore the SSH cert on Azure virtual machines?

Tags: azure, ssh, rsa, x509

I created some linux virtual machines in Azure and during the creation I uploaded an X509 certificate to enable SSH login. Everything worked perfectly and I could login via SSH.

Later I created a SSH key pair to allow my deploy machine to connect to the Azure virtual machines to deploy my app. I used puppet to install the SSH RSA public key to the Azure virtual machines and now I can no longer connect via SSH to any of them. I cannot connect using the X509 cert I added during creation or the new installed RSA key.

- Is there a way, via Azure portal, to replace the X509 cert? or restore the previous one?
- Why would Azure SSH connection break by adding an additional RSA public key?
- The virtual machines are still getting their configuration from Puppet so is there a way
  to configure puppet so it restores the X509 cert?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it had nothing to do with the keys. My configuration server (puppet) modified also the sshd_config file and set UsePAM to no. This causes Azure to fail all key based login attempts. After changing UsePAM to yes I can log normally.